# Line spacing in jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am developing an editor in java.I want to set line spacing in `JTextpane`.

I am using the following code to set Line spacing,However it does not change the line spacing.Can anyone please guide me.

```
SimpleAttributeSet lineSpace=new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(lineSpace,1.5f);      
doc.setParagraphAttributes(startPos, lengthOfString, lineSpace,false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls provide more code.

Comment: For me the code is correct. There is an error somewhere else

Comment: @StanislavL-Could there be any problem with using htmlEditorKit.Because i have tried every possible thing but line spacing does not change. –

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the program. I have used line spacing on a text pane with normal text and it works fine when you have a new line string. Maybe with HTML is doesn't work because you don't have a newline string and the text just wraps? Or maybe the problem is your startPos, lenthOfString variables.

Comment: @StanislavL,@camickr-i did try the above code on an jtextpane which does not have htmleditorkit on it and it worked.However it does not work on a jtextpane that has a htmlEditorkit installed in it,can anyone help me on how to implement line spacing in a jtextpane which has an htmleditorkit installed on it.

Comment: Is there anyone who can provide a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204675/how-to-set-the-line-spacing-in-a-jtextpane. I have a solution for that question.